# Optimization in Python with Multiple Functions and a Linear Constraint (Linear Programming Problem Query)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming

I'm a little new to optimization in Python, particularly on Scipy. If I only have one function such as this:

```
def prod(x):
    return -x[0] * x[1]
```

Then I can easily know how to do maximization through:

```
linear_constraint = LinearConstraint([[1,1]], [20], [20])
x0 = np.array([15,5])
result = minimize(prod, x0, constraints=linear_constraint)
print(result['x'])
```

This is basically maximizing `x0 * x1` given the constraint that `x0 + x1 = 20`. The answer here is `array([10., 10.])`.

So now, I wish to do something more sophisticated and not just optimizing one function. Suppose I would like to optimize multiple functions. Say I have this matrix `P` of size `n x 3`:

```
A     B     C
3     2     7
6     3     4
8     1     5
...
```

Is there a way to optimize (minimize) `P[i] * x`, where `*` here is a dot product for all `i = 1..n`? In short, I wish to optimize:

```
3*x[0] + 2*x[1] + 7*x[2]
6*x[0] + 3*x[1] + 4*x[2]
8*x[0] + 1*x[1] + 5*x[2]
...
```

and under the constraint that `x[0] + x[1] + x[2] = 1`. Anyone knows how to implement this correctly on Python (I'm using Scipy by the way)? I'm still not sure where to begin. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For standard optimization tools, the objective function must return a **scalar**. This is called a "**single objective**". There is a branch in optimization that deals with **multiple objectives** (with names like vector optimization, multiple objective optimization and multiple criteria optimization). There is a wide literature about this. I suggest doing some reading to get familiar with the concepts, ideas and algorithms for this.

Comment: I thought about obtaining a vector by multiplying this array (or matrix) of size n x 3  by the 3 x 1 vector [x0, x1, x2]. As a result, I would get an n x 1 vector. And then find the L2-Norm of this vector. Then minimize on that norm (scalar); as opposed to trying to minimize multiple functions all at once. Not sure if that's the right way to do it... Thoughts?

Comment: I don't know. That is just a very different problem, You stated a multi-objective problem. If you do min ||Px|| you have a single objective problem.

Comment: Hmmm, but why does it have to be a multi-objective problem? Can't I just frame it into a single objective problem? So basically computing Px just gives me a vector. And if I want to "minimize" my vector, then I'll do so by find the minimum of the L2 norm of the resultant vector.

Comment: Sure. You can redefine the objective to anything you want. It would be one of the possible scalarizations.